# Nested function calls in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I am trying to covert this line of coffeescript:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

I just copied and pasted the same thing into the coffeescript file, since it looked valid, but I ran into a problem:

```
error: unexpected CALL_END

C:/nodejs/coffee.cmd --map --compile test.coffee
test.coffee:20:1: error: reserved word "static"
static
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Works fine here. Can you give an SSCCE?

Comment: You can use [Fiddle Salad](http://fiddlesalad.com/coffeescript/) to post an SSCCE.

Comment: [Worksforme](http://coffeescript.org/#try:app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname%2C%20'public'%29%29%29%3B). Is this a node exception or a coffeescript conversion error?

Comment: You must be using a very old version of CoffeeScript if it complains about `static` being a keyword in this context.

Comment: Is your CoffeeScript up to date?

Comment: Nope, have the latest version of coffeescript. 1.6.3

Comment: I have the same issue with coffee-script ```1.7.1``` which is the most up to date version, but I'm using ```mocha-test``` grunt task to run tests written in coffee-script and ```grunt@0.4.5``` is shipped with ```coffee-script@1.3.3```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something seems wrong with your coffeescript install. I'm doing the same thing you're doing and it's all fine.

```
$ cat temp.coffee
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

$ coffee -cm temp.coffee

$ cat temp.js
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.6.2
(function() {
  app.use(express["static"](path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

}).call(this);

/*
//@ sourceMappingURL=temp.map
*/
$ cat temp.map 
{
  "version": 3,
  "file": "temp.js",
  "sourceRoot": "",
  "sources": [
    "temp.coffee"
  ],
  "names": [],
  "mappings": ";AAAA;CAAA,CAAA,CAAG,CAAwB,GAAZ,CAAA,CAAQ;CAAvB"
}

$ coffee -v
CoffeeScript version 1.6.2

$ which coffee
/usr/bin/coffee
```

Try following these steps and let me know what happens.

Comment: ```coffee -cm temp.coffee``` works fine for me but still doesn't work with my other file. ```coffee -v``` respond ```CoffeeScript version 1.7.1```